# TypeError: loads() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-mail, itsdangerous

i am using itsdangerous for generating token's for email confirmation  and i want it to be expire after some time but i am getting this error: "TypeError: loads() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_age' "

Here's the code:

```
@app.route('/email_confirm/<token>')
def confirm_mail(token):
    email = s.loads(token, salt='email-confirm', max_age=20)
    return '<h1>The token works !</h1>'
```

Comment: I think you are not using `TimedSerializer`?  https://github.com/pallets/itsdangerous/blob/920993c48a41a322ae85ecfaa6fa43fcce1b1089/src/itsdangerous/timed.py#L118

Comment: my import looks like this: from itsdangerous import URLSafeSerializer

Comment: use `from itsdangerous import TimedSerializer`